# Finding correlation between function input and output

Tags: statistics, neural-networks

I'm trying to get a value for a correlation between a function input and its output. One brute force way to get this is to sample the entire space and find the standard deviation of the resulting outputs.

Is there a less expensive way to find this correlation, perhaps by differentiating the equation?

For more context, I'm trying to see how much a particular input affects each output of a neural network (nothing to do with tuning weights).

Comment: Well you could always compute the gradient of the network w.r.t. each value of $x$ to see how much the input can impact the output. You can also sample the input space and find the measure of correlation $\rho$ between $x, f(x)$ if thats what you're after

Comment: @wjmccann I dont get your second point. what is "the measure of correlation"